# Error in using Fast Android Networking API in project

Tags: java, android, apiclient, android-api-31, fast-android-networking

I have been working on a project and using the fast android networking api. I have added the below dependency - ( implementation 'com.amitshekhar.android:android-networking:1.0.2') in the gradle module file and also added the internet permission in Android Manifesto File. Still Android Studio is not able to fetch the "AndroidNetworking" Class and it's giving it as red underlined.

```
Gradle module
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.apirequestusingfastandroidnetworking'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.apirequestusingfastandroidnetworking"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.amitshekhar.android:android-networking:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
}
```

```
package com.example.apirequestusingfastandroidnetworking;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        
        String url= "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users";  //using get api

        AndroidNetworking.initialize(this);
        AndroidNetworking.get(url);
    }
}
```

Can somebody tell me that what could be issue bcoz of which android id not fetching the "AndroidNetworking".